# The universe of discourse is N for $ \forall x(x < 7 \rightarrow \exists a \exists b \exists c (a^2 + b^2 +c^2 =x))$

Tags: logic

The universe of discourse is N for  $$ \forall x(x < 7 \rightarrow \exists a \exists b \exists c (a^2 + b^2 +c^2 =x))$$
Does universe of discourse N, also apply for a,b,c ?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: ok. thanks.....